# VC++ New Header Files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm using VC++ 2010, and already have a project working from a downloaded example. I go to add a new header file, but it doesn't show up when trying to add it in a cpp file. Is there like a refresh thing I need to do? I complie the project before trying to include it in a cpp file but nothing shows up.

Any ideas?

Thanks much,

David

Comment: Are you saying Intellisense didn't recognize the header, or that you have a compile error?

Comment: Where are you adding the header? Is it to the project/solution or are you copying it to the sdk include directory?

Comment: Hi. I figured out what it is. This is a straightup bug(I think). It doesn't show up in intellisense when adding a new file from the ide. But if you drag and drop one in from the file system, it now shows up in intellisense.